# Handling Data Transmission in Foreground Service with WebSocket and Managing Downtime

Tags: android, flutter, location, background-process, foreground-service

I've developed [an application](https://github.com/hasanisaeed/always-awake-flutter) that needs to continuously track and share a user's location and speed with a server in real-time. For this purpose, the app runs a foreground service and utilizes WebSocket for live data sharing. However, I've encountered two main challenges:

1. There might be instances when the device loses internet connectivity while attempting to send data.
2. The user may not use their phone for several hours, leading to the device's screen turning off.

**Approaches to solve these challenges:**

**For the first challenge,** if the device lacks internet access, the data is temporarily stored in the *local database*. Once internet connectivity is restored, the stored data is automatically sent to the server.

**For the second challenge,** I request additional permissions from the user and include them in the `Manifest.xml`, such as `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` to keep the phone awake and `android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` to receive location updates in the background.

**Issue:**

The problem occurs when the application successfully receives data for about an hour and a half but then fails to continue operating in the foreground, leading to the service being terminated.

**Code Snippets:**

I'm using [flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task). Below is a snippet from the `CustomTaskHandler` class, where I send the data to the server in the `onRepeatEvent` method. This method retrieves the current location of the user and attempts to send it via WebSocket. If the transmission fails, the data is saved in the local database.

```dart
class CustomTaskHandler extends TaskHandler {
...
  @override
  void onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    final locationData = await locationService.getCurrentLocation();
    if (locationData != null) {
      log(">> Current Location: (${locationData.latitude}, ${locationData.longitude})");
      FlutterForegroundTask.updateService(
        notificationTitle: 'Current Location ($count): (${locationData.latitude}, ${locationData.longitude})',
      );

      final formattedTimestamp = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(timestamp);
      final locationMap = {
        'latitude': locationData.latitude,
        'longitude': locationData.longitude,
        'speed': locationData.speed,
        'created_at': formattedTimestamp.toString()
      };
      final hasInternetConnection = await checkInternetConnection();
      if (hasInternetConnection) {
        log(">> Send via websocket.");
        _initWebsocket();
        websocket.sendMessage(locationMap);
      } else {
        locationRepository.insertRecord(
          speed: locationMap['speed'].toString(),
          latitude: locationMap['latitude'].toString(),
          longitude: locationMap['longitude'].toString(),
          createdAt: locationMap['created_at'].toString(),
        )
        .then((_) => log(">> Record inserted successfully"))
        .catchError((error) => log(">> Error inserting record: $error"));
      }

      sendPort?.send(locationMap);
    }
  }
```

The complete code, along with a demo, is available on [my repository](https://github.com/hasanisaeed/always-awake-flutter).

**Question:**

Do you have any suggestions on how to ensure that the foreground service continues to run and transmit data without being interrupted, especially after long periods of inactivity or when the device is not in use?

Comment: There is nothing you can do on Android to force a service to run continuously.  The OS can and will eventually kill any service, even a foreground one.  A foreground one is just higher on the keep priority list.  What you need to do is take a step back and think about how frequently you actually need the location, especially on a device that's gone to sleep.  And consider if Android is the right OS for your device.

Comment: I'd also consider other options for keep alive.  How frequently do you need to get the location?  How exact do you need the location?  If you can live with an update every 2 minutes, setting a repeating alarm via alarm manager is better than a service, and will automatically start the app, with nothing running in background (you would probably need to whitelist the app from power management to make this work through Doze).  It would also GREATLY improve your power usage over a wakelock

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for your insights. Regarding your suggestion to reconsider how frequently the location data is actually needed, I've been contemplating adjusting the data transmission interval. Instead of collecting and sending location data every second, I'm considering updating it to once every minute or more. This approach should significantly reduce the workload on the device and align better with Android's power management policies. Would this adjustment potentially mitigate the issue with the service being killed by the OS, in your opinion?

Comment: Possibly, but I won't promise that.  The exact parameters at which Android will kill a foreground Service can change from version to version.  If you can up it to 2 minutes, using an alarm and power whitelisting would probably work better (alarms have a 2 minute minimum time IIRC, although it has been a while).  But pretty much any attempt to make a service last long term on Android is going to hit a failure point eventually, the OS is just optimized against it for power management reasons.

Comment: Just had an interesting thought-  have you considered trying a geofence?  A geofence wakes up your app (including restarting it) when a user enters or leaves a radius.  https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/geofencing  Setting a geofence around your current location and getting woken up when a user moves far enough away (and then writing the new location to db/server) might be a way to do this without keeping a service around

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, Gabe, for the geofencing suggestion. I hadn't thought about using it to balance real-time tracking with power efficiency. Setting a geofence to wake the app when the user moves significantly could indeed reduce the need for a constant service and align with Android's resource management. I'll look into this approach and its implementation. Appreciate your guidance!